# Конфигурация nginx-овского конфига

Tags: nginx, apache2.2, config

Доброго времени суток.
Эх, программист я, но не админ, так что прошу помощи у Вас.
Кому не сложно, помогите, пожалуйста, переписать данную конфигурацию `htaccess`-а под `nginx`-овский конфиг.
**Спасибо большое :)**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.php
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=2 [L,QSA]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} public\/ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(jpg|gif|png|ico|flv|htm|html|php|css|js)$
  RewriteRule . - [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
FileETag Size
```

Comment: Если не сложно уточните для чего предназначено каждое `RewriteRule`, возможно будет проще в каких-то случаях обойтись без rewrite

Answer (score 1):

Это не совсем точно, но тестировать не на чем

```
location /public {}
location / {
    rewrite ^/index\.php$ index.php?rewrite=2 last;
    rewrite ^/$ index.php?rewrite=1 last;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ index.php?rewrite=1 last;
}
location ~ \.(jpg|gif|png|ico|flv|htm|html|php|css|js)$ {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Могу порекомендовать онлайн-конвертер htaccess в nginx: http://winginx.ru/htaccess